# Does permission_level (_self) means that only contract can use this method?

Tags: eosio-code, c++

If yes, then how do I make sure that anyone or any specified address can call a method? If not then what is the usage of `permission_level (_self ...)`?

```
 action{
    permission_level{_self, "active"_n},
    inf_account,
    "bet"_n, memo}
}.play();
```

Answer (score 1):

Correct, it means only the account on which the contract resides can call this action. In general, `_self` refers to the instance of `eosio::name` that contains the account name where the contract resides